# Google Tag Manager - CSS selector challenge

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get the URL of a link in the source code. The challenge is that the URL is hidden behind a image, and thus only letting me fetch the image-url.

I've been trying to figure a way to solve this issue by using the new CSS selector in the trigger system and also made a DOM variable that should get the URL when the image is clicked. There can also be multiple downloads.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
<div> 
 <div class="download">
  <a href="example.com/The-URL-I-Want-to-get-if-top-image-is-clicked.pdf" target="_blank">
   <img src="some-download-image.png"/></a>
 <div class="download">
  <a href="example.com/Another-URL-I-Want-to-get-if-middle-image-is-clicked.pdf" target="_blank">
   <img src="some-download-image.png"/></a>
 <div class="download">
  <a href="example.com/Last-URL-I-Want-to-get-if-bottom-image-is-clicked.pdf" target="_blank">
   <img src="some-download-image.png"/></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

There are much code above and below this snippet, but with the selector it should be fairly easy to get the information I want. Only that I don't.

If anyone have met this wall and solved it, I really would like to know how. :)

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the href attribute of the {{Click Element}} variable? So whichever link is clicked, your gtm.linkClick event will be associated with a clicked element. You can check in the dev console by analysing the dataLayer object that gets created from the link click.

Comment: @nyuen I will certainly try that. I think I actually tried something similar, but second time is the charm :)

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the site so that I can take a look?

Comment: @nyuen did not work out. Maybe you could supply me with an example on how you would do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible solution. So as I understand it, you would like to grab the anchor element's href attribute when you click the "download" image.

A Custom Javascript variable would need to be created so that you can manipulate the click element object:

```
function(){
   var ec = {{Click Element}};
   var href = $(ec).closest('a').attr('href');
   return href;
}
```

So you will need to do your due diligence and add in your error checking and stuff, but basically this should return to you the href, and then you will need to parse the string to extract the portion that you need.

Comment: Great! I've torn my hair out all day. Thanks for an elegant and effective solution! :)

Comment: No problem, save the hair loss for when you're much older. ;)